# Event Calendar for php website

Tags: php, events, calendar, google-calendar-api, icalendar

We want to use an event calendar for one of our PHP project. It needs below features

Switching Views – Daily, Weekly and Monthly.

Create Events.

Invite other user to Events

Share Calendars (Users should be able to see others calendar and their availability)

We have tried google calendar API, but it is not working properly for us. Is there any other APIs or tools which you can recommend?

Comment: Could you describe what isn't working properly in the Google Calendar API? It could give us a better idea of what you're looking for instead.

Comment: @Frank We were trying to use single google account to manage all calendars in Google Calendar. So for each user we will create one calendar and try to fetch the data. Also we want to do above features with this API. Is this possible? Also we did not see a good php implementaion of google calendar. Google's documentation was having their inrtegration with zend. But we are looking for independent integration without zend

Answer (score 0):

i have made one project in which i have made calender ...

it does not fulfill your requirement but still you can customize it ..

here is the code

```
$strt_date = '01-04-2011';
$end_date = '05-07-2011';
$date_array = array();
$date_array = explode('-',$strt_date);
$back_strt_date = $date_array[2]."-".$date_array[0]."-".$date_array[1];// YYYY-MM-DD
$front_strt_date = $date_array[1]."-".$date_array[0]."-".$date_array[2];// MM-DD-YYYY
$date_array = array();
$date_array = explode('-',$end_date);
$back_bk_date = $date_array[2]."-".$date_array[0]."-".$date_array[1]; // YYYY-MM-DD
$front_end_date = $date_array[1]."-".$date_array[0]."-".$date_array[2]; // MM-DD-YYYY
// fetching data for selected date interval
//$rs_couse_cnt = get_course_cnt($back_strt_date,$back_bk_date);
if($rs_couse_cnt =='No record Found'){
    echo "No Records Found.";
    exit;
}
// converting string in to TIMESTAMP
$sdate = strtotime($front_strt_date);
$edate = strtotime($front_end_date);

//getting starting and ending month of date...
$st_dt = array();
$en_dt = array();
    // exploding date string in to array
    $st_dt = explode('-',$strt_date); 
    $en_dt = explode('-',$end_date); 

    // assigning month value to variables...
    $st_mon = $st_dt[0];
    $en_mon = $en_dt[0];

    // calculating month diff..
    $mon_diff = $en_mon - $st_mon;

    // assinging year value to variables....
    $st_year = $st_dt[2];
    $en_year = $en_dt[2];

//converting TIMESTAMP into desired date format...
$st_date = date('F jS Y',$sdate);
$en_date = date('F jS Y',$edate);

echo " <center><h2>$st_date - $en_date</h2></center>";
//echo " <br />start month is $st_mon & end month is $en_mon & month diff is $mon_diff";
//echo " <br />start year is $st_year & end year is $en_year";
$ttl_cnt =0;
for($i=$st_mon;($st_year<=$en_year);$i++){
    $end = $en_mon+1;
    if($i == $end && $st_year == $en_year){
        break;
    }
    // this will continue until all months are completed
    $st_mon_time_stamp = mktime(0,0,0,$i,1,$st_year);
    echo "<br /><br /><center> <h3> ".date("F Y",$st_mon_time_stamp)."</h3></center>";
    $no_of_days = date("t",$st_mon_time_stamp);
    $str_cal ='<table border="1px" width="100%">
                <thead>
                    <th>Sunday</th>
                    <th>Monday</th>
                    <th>Tuesday</th>
                    <th>Wednesday</th>
                    <th>Thursday</th>
                    <th>Friday</th>
                    <th>Saturday</th>
                </thead>
                <tbody>';
    $cnt = 1;
    $week = 0;
    $mon_cnt = 0;
    for($j=1;$j<=$no_of_days;$j++){
        if($cnt >= $no_of_days){
            break;
        }
        if($cnt == 1){
            // for first row....
            $time_stamp = mktime(0,0,0,$i,$cnt,$st_year);
            $str_cal .='<tr>';
            if(date("l",$time_stamp) == 'Sunday'){
                $space = 0;
            }
            else if(date("l",$time_stamp) == 'Monday'){
                $space = 1;
            }
            else if(date("l",$time_stamp) == 'Tuesday'){
                $space = 2;
            }
            else if(date("l",$time_stamp) == 'Wednesday'){
                $space = 3;
            }
            else if(date("l",$time_stamp) == 'Thursday'){
                $space = 4;
            }
            else if(date("l",$time_stamp) == 'Friday'){
                $space = 5;
            }
            else if(date("l",$time_stamp) == 'Saturday'){
                $space = 6;
            }
            $dis = 7 - $space; //exit;
            while($space != 0){
                // this will display spaces in first row...
                $str_cal .='<td>&nbsp;</td>';
                $space--; 
            }
            while($dis != 0){
                // this will display calender date in first row...
                if(strlen($i) == 1 && strlen($cnt)==1){
                    $date = $st_year.'-0'.$i.'-0'.$cnt;
                }
                else{
                    $date = $st_year.'-'.$i.'-'.$cnt;
                }
                $flg = 0;
                for($rs=0;$rs<count($rs_couse_cnt);$rs++){                      
                    if($rs_couse_cnt[$rs]['EnrolledDate'] == $date){
                        $time_stmp = strtotime($date);
                        $str_cal .='<td>'.date('j S',$time_stmp).'<br /><br />Count : <a href="light_box_course.php" onClick="$.showAkModal(\'light_box_course.php?type=list&session_id='.$session_id.'&campus_id='.$campus_id.'&strt_date='.$rs_couse_cnt[$rs]['EnrolledDate'].'&end_date='.$rs_couse_cnt[$rs]['EnrolledDate'].'\',\'\',500,500);return false;">'.$rs_couse_cnt[$rs]['CourseCount'].'</a></td>';       
                        $cnt++;
                        $mon_cnt += $rs_couse_cnt[$rs]['CourseCount'];
                        $flg = 1;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if($flg == 0){
                    $time_stmp = strtotime($date);
                    $str_cal .='<td>'.date('j S',$time_stmp).'<br /><br />&nbsp;</td>'; 
                    $cnt++;
                }
                $dis--;
            }           
            $str_cal .='</tr>';     
        }
        else{
            // for rest of the rows...
            $str_cal .='<tr>';
            for($w=0;$w<7;$w++){
                if($cnt<=$no_of_days){
                    if(strlen($i) == 1){
                        $date = $st_year.'-0'.$i.'-'.$cnt;
                    }
                    else{
                        $date = $st_year.'-'.$i.'-'.$cnt;
                    }
                    $flg = 0;
                    for($rs=0;$rs<count($rs_couse_cnt);$rs++){
                        if($rs_couse_cnt[$rs]['EnrolledDate'] == $date){ 
                            $time_stmp = strtotime($date);
                            $str_cal .='<td>'.date('j S',$time_stmp).'<br /><br />Count :<a href="light_box_course.php" onClick="$.showAkModal(\'light_box_course.php?type=list&session_id='.$session_id.'&campus_id='.$campus_id.'&strt_date='.$rs_couse_cnt[$rs]['EnrolledDate'].'&end_date='.$rs_couse_cnt[$rs]['EnrolledDate'].'\',\'\',500,500);return false;">'.$rs_couse_cnt[$rs]['CourseCount'].'</a></td>';        
                            $flg = 1;
                            $cnt++;
                            $mon_cnt += $rs_couse_cnt[$rs]['CourseCount'];
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    if($flg == 0){
                        $time_stmp = strtotime($date);
                        $str_cal .='<td>'.date('j S',$time_stmp).'<br /><br />&nbsp;</td>';
                        $cnt++;
                    }
                }
                else{
                    $str_cal .='<td>&nbsp;</td>';
                }
            }
            $str_cal .='</tr>';
        }
    }
    $ttl_cnt += $mon_cnt;
    if($mon_cnt != 0){
        $str_cal .='<tr>
                        <td> Monthly Count :</td> 
                        <td colspan="6"><a href="light_box_course.php" onClick="$.showAkModal(\'light_box_course.php?type=list&session_id='.$session_id.'&campus_id='.$campus_id.'&strt_date='.$st_year."-".(strlen($i)==1?"0".$i:$i)."-"."01".'&end_date='.$st_year."-".(strlen($i)==1?"0".$i:$i)."-".$no_of_days.'\',\'\',500,500);return false;">'.$mon_cnt.'</td>
                    </tr>';
    }else{
        $str_cal .='<tr>
                        <td> Monthly Count :</td> 
                        <td colspan="6">'.$mon_cnt.'</td>
                    </tr>';
    }
        $str_cal .='</tbody>
                </table>';
    if($i == 12){
        $i=0;
        $st_year ++;
    }
    echo $str_cal;  
}
```

?>